# bot dando build infinito

Tags: javascript, node.js, chatbot

Eu to codando um bot do Whatsapp, e ele está funcionando corretamente, mas quando coloco ele no netlify, funciona, mas o problema é que depois de escanear o código QR para fazer login, ele mostra a mensagem "Client is ready!", mas ele continua dando building, o que devo fazer para resolver isso?

```
const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth()
})

client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true})
})


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
})
```

Ele chega nessa parte do "Client is Ready" e o bot funciona, posso mandar peguntar no whatsapp e ele funciona, porem no netlify o status segue como "building" e depois de um tempo ele fecha pelo o programa "não dar resposta", o que eu tenho que fazer ?

erro que o netlify mostra depois de muito tempo em building

```
10:03:13 PM: Client is ready!
10:20:21 PM: Failed during stage "building site": Command did not finish within the time limit
10:20:21 PM: Execution timed out after 18m30.001227035s
10:20:21 PM: Error running command: Command did not finish within the time limit
10:20:21 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:20:22 PM: Finished processing build request in 18m42.831s
```

Comment: [Essa pergunta já foi feita](/q/587565/70). Queira tratar do assunto conforme orientações na primeira postagem. Para evitar duplicação de informações o espaço de comentários foi desativado nesta postagem mas ainda pode ser usado na postagem original.